# webpack 2 livereload not working when I edit files

Tags: webpack

I'm trying to setup Livereload with webpack 2. Apparently, the way to achieve this is to enable HMR. So, I did this in the config

```
var path = require('path');
var HtmlWebpackPlugin = require('html-webpack-plugin');
var ExtractTextPlugin = require('extract-text-webpack-plugin');


module.exports = {
    entry: './app/src/scripts/index.js',
    output: {
        filename: 'app.js',
        path: path.resolve('app/assets/js')
    },
    module: {
        rules: [
        {
            test: /\.scss$/, 
            use: ExtractTextPlugin.extract({
                fallback: "style-loader",
                use: ['css-loader', 'sass-loader']
            })
        }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new ExtractTextPlugin('../css/style.css')
    ],
    devServer: {
        hot: true,
        compress: true,
        port: 8080,
        publicPath: 'http://localhost:8080/',
        clientLogLevel: 'none',
        contentBase: (__dirname, './'),
        watchContentBase: true,
        watchOptions: {
            aggregateTimeout: 300,
            poll: 1000
        }
    }
};
```

and my package.json looks like this

```
"scripts": {
    "watch": "webpack --progress --colors --watch",
    "build": "webpack --progress --colors",
    "deploy": "NODE_ENV=production webpack -p --progress --colors",
    "start": "webpack-dev-server"
  },
```

I'm trying to do `npm start` which serves the index.html at root on port 8080 but when I edit my scss, I the page doesn't reload. Also, I have to run `webpack --watch` in a separate terminal to see changes reflect when I manually reload the page in browser.

How can I fix these two issues?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To enable hot module replacement you also need to change your entry to:

```
entry: [
  'webpack-dev-server/client?http://localhost:8080',
  'webpack/hot/only-dev-server',
  './app/src/scripts/index.js'
],
```

And add the `HotModuleReplacementPlugin` to your plugins:

```
new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
```

As shown in [Guides - Hot Module Replacement React](https://webpack.js.org/guides/hmr-react/#using-webpack-with-a-config) (just without the `react-hot-loader`).

Alternatively you can use the `--hot` CLI flag to enable it for you without having to change the config.

```
"start": "webpack-dev-server --hot"
```

Reloading after editing a `.scss` file is another issue, because you're using `extract-text-webpack-plugin` and HMR in the browser will tell you that nothing changed, although it recompiled the bundle, because it doesn't watch the output CSS file. To get around that, you can disable the extract text plugin in development with its [`disable` option](https://github.com/webpack-contrib/extract-text-webpack-plugin#options), which makes it fallback to the `style-loader` you configured. You would need to change it in your plugins section to:

```
new ExtractTextPlugin({
  filename: '../css/style.css',
  disable: process.env.NODE_ENV !== 'production'
}),
```

> Also, I have to run `webpack --watch` in a separate terminal to see changes reflect when I manually reload the page in browser.

You're probably serving the files from your file system, instead of getting the ones in memory from `webpack-dev-server`, which does not write any file to disk. You're importing the `html-webpack-plugin` but not actually using it. After adding it to the plugins section `webpack-dev-server` will also serve the HTML file from memory when you visit `http://localhost:8080/`.

Comment: Great! Thank you!